# Machine learning to understand website structure in Python

Tags: machine-learning, web-crawler, pybrain

I have been working on crawling webpages and extracting the elements of the website.
Ex:
Given a website - The crawler should return the following sections: Header, Menu, Footer, content etc.

I was thinking that it would be great if I could use machine learning to train the code to learn how to classify websites.

I tried looking at Python Machine learning libraries (ex: PyBrain) but the examples are very complex.
Can anyone please suggest me a library and some tutorial on how to get started on using Python Machine Learning with some simple examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MLPy](https://mlpy.fbk.eu/) may be a simpler start for you.
Here is a link to the [documentation on classification](https://mlpy.fbk.eu/data/doc/classification.html). By the way, if you don't know what the classes should look like, maybe you need to [cluster](https://mlpy.fbk.eu/data/doc/clustering.html) your pages, and not to classify them.